# Relationship between GeneralJournalAccountEntry and LedgerJournalTrans_Project

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

We are attempting to relate GL transactions `GeneralJournalAccountEntry` with their appropriate Project Category Id `LedgerJournalTrans_Project`, but are having a very difficult time relating the two tables.

We can get there by this route:

- GeneralJournalAccountEntry.GeneralJournalEntry = GeneralJournalEntry.RecId (Many to 1)
- GeneralJournalEntry.SubLedgerVoucher = LedgerJournalTrans.Voucher (1 to Many)
- LedgerJournalTrans.RecId = LedgerJournalTrans_Project.RefRecId (1 to 1)

But the individual leg of the transaction gets lost in the Many to 1 and 1 to Many relationships.  We understand the tables are from different "modules", but are hoping there is some way to connect the two without depending on something messy like transaction amount.

Is this possible, or is there another way to accomplish our goal?

Comment: I assume that you have read the 'Mapping the LedgerTrans table to General Journal Tables (White paper) [AX 2012]'?
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh292603.aspx

Comment: I actually had not seen that yet, thanks for posting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a one-to-one relationship.

The closest thing would be to use Voucher and TransDate on LedgerJournalTrans to fetch ledger transactions.

See [this post](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/106760.aspx).

There is a white paper describing the [AX 2012 ledger posting framework](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/5/015E8CAD-0417-4BE5-8F6B-87DD28A8BED7/Updating%20the%20Uses%20of%20the%20Ledger%20Posting%20Framework%20for%20Microsoft%20Dynamics%20AX%202012.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Jan.  It appears we either need another approach or a way to get that information included in the posting framework...

Comment: Good luck with that, it is not standard.

Comment: I have been looking at the same thing and I think 'Good luck' is exactly right.  I'm not convinced there is a way to do it.  Keep in mind that General Journals can be deleted, even after posting.  There are even jobs to do that in AX.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain yet that I have this completely figured out, but I think this can be used to create a similar link.  I'm trying to link the generaljournalaccountentry line items to the inventjounrnaltrans line items.  This should provide the link between the two tables based on the voucher and line item number and give me the itemid.  I would think there would necessarily be a similar link to the project because of the ability to navigate that way in the front end application.  It might also be helpful to trace the SQL query when performing the action in the front end.

```
SELECT itp.[PARTITION]
     , itp.[DATAAREAID]
     , itp.[TRANSDATE]
     , itp.[VOUCHER]
     , itp.[ITEMID]
     , itojt.[INVENTJOURNALLINENUM]
     , MAX(ito.[REFERENCEID]) AS [REFERENCEID]
FROM [dbo].[INVENTTRANSPOSTING] itp WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[INVENTTRANSORIGIN] ito WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON ito.[RECID] = itp.[INVENTTRANSORIGIN]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[INVENTTRANSORIGINJOURNALTRANS] itojt WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON itojt.[INVENTTRANSORIGIN] = ito.[RECID]
WHERE (itp.[INVENTTRANSPOSTINGTYPE] = 1 OR itp.[INVENTTRANSPOSTINGTYPE] = 0)
      AND itp.[ISPOSTED] = 1
GROUP BY itp.[PARTITION]
       , itp.[DATAAREAID]
       , itp.[TRANSDATE]
       , itp.[VOUCHER]
       , itp.[ITEMID]
       , itojt.[INVENTJOURNALLINENUM]
```