# How to retrieve data from LedgerJournalTrans table (based on relations and joins) for voucher transaction form in D365FinOp?

Tags: sql-server, join, axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

Basically I have a client request to implement:
Need to show data from the following fields : PaymMode, BankChequeNum, LedgerDimensionName, JournalNum from **ledgerJournalTrans** table on the LedgerTransVoucher form but have been unable to do so have tried nearly all of the possible queries that I could think of but none of them are working the way I expect them to: either the query is doing a cartesian product and duplicating the records or it is displaying no data in those fields.
Below is the query that I have recently tried:

```
public display MH_AccountTitle displayBeneficiaryName(GeneralJournalAccountEntry _accountEntry) 

{ 
    select SubledgerVoucher, AccountingDate from journalEntry 
        where journalEntry.RecId == _accountEntry.GeneralJournalEntry 
            join Voucher, MH_AccountTitle, RecId, AmountCurDebit, AmountCurCredit, TransDate from LedgerTrans  
                where LedgerTrans.Voucher == journalEntry.SubledgerVoucher 
                && LedgerTrans.TransDate  == journalEntry.AccountingDate 
                && LedgerTrans.PaymReference == _accountEntry.PaymentReference 
                && (abs(_accountEntry.TransactionCurrencyAmount) == LedgerTrans.AmountCurDebit 
                || abs(_accountEntry.TransactionCurrencyAmount) == LedgerTrans.AmountCurCredit); 

    return ledgerTrans.MH_AccountTitle; 

}
```

I know this query is logically incorrect because joins can't be applied on the basis of date and amount but this was suggested by a senior of mine after all else failed, and it did work, records were returned correctly but it failed where there were multiple transactions with same **TransactionCurrencyAmount,TransDate** and voucher
join with **PaymentReference** also failed where the method of payment was not Check and hence there was no BankChequeNum/Payment reference resulting in the same problem

Anyone who has any idea of what could be work around for this?

**Note:**
work has been done on a custom form of LedgerTransVoucher
display method approach was used because simply applying joins on the form's data source didn't work
Also code has been written on **form's datasource GeneralJournalAccountEntry**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relationship between GeneralJournalAccountEntry and LedgerJournalTrans\_Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965170/relationship-between-generaljournalaccountentry-and-ledgerjournaltrans-project)

Comment: Also take a look at https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/f/dynamics-365-for-finance-and-operations-forum/425467/relationship-join-between-generaljournalaccountentry-and-trans-tables

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do to debug these kinds of issues is get the query string that X++ creates when using inline SQL. Often there is something that X++ translates into SQL that is not expected.

Secondly, I always write my queries in SSMS first to avoid having unwanted results because of the X++ translation to SQL query.

You can get the query string by either making a query object and using the .ToString() method or you can take a trace and use Traceparser to view the query that was sent to the SQL Server.

I am thinking the abs() functions will be the issue here.